# Can I perform binary tree search with the standard library without wrapping the float type and abusing the BTreeMap?

Tags: rust, floating-point

I would like to find the first element which is greater than a limit from an **ordered** collection. While iteration over it is always an option, I need a faster one. Currently, I came up with a solution like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f4b3c3b00e6102aac5563a06a22b78cd) but it feels a little hacky:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::ops::Bound::{Included, Unbounded};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct FloatWrapper(f32);

impl Eq for FloatWrapper {}

impl PartialEq for FloatWrapper {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        (self.0 - other.0).abs() < 1.17549435e-36f32
    }
}

impl Ord for FloatWrapper {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        if (self.0 - other.0).abs() < 1.17549435e-36f32 {
            Ordering::Equal
        } else if self.0 - other.0 > 0.0 {
            Ordering::Greater
        } else if self.0 - other.0 < 0.0 {
            Ordering::Less
        } else {
            Ordering::Equal
        }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for FloatWrapper {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}
```

- The wrapper around the float is not nice even that I am sure that there will be no NaNs
- The `Range` is also unnecessary since I want a single element.

Is there a better way of achieving a similar result using only Rust's standard library? I know that there are plenty of tree implementations but it feels like overkill.

After the suggestions [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58238731/155423) to use the iterator I did a little benchmark with the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let measure = vec![
        10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190,
        200,
    ];

    let mut measured_binary = Vec::new();
    let mut measured_iter = Vec::new();
    let mut measured_vec = Vec::new();

    for size in measure {
        let mut ww = BTreeMap::new();
        let mut what_found = Vec::new();
        for _ in 0..size {
            let now: f32 = thread_rng().gen_range(0.0, 1.0);
            ww.insert(FloatWrapper(now), now);
        }
        let what_to_search: Vec<FloatWrapper> = (0..10000)
            .map(|_| thread_rng().gen_range(0.0, 0.8))
            .map(|x| FloatWrapper(x))
            .collect();
        let mut rez = 0;

        for current in &what_to_search {
            let now = Instant::now();
            let m = find_one(&ww, current);
            rez += now.elapsed().as_nanos();
            what_found.push(m);
        }

        measured_binary.push(rez);
        rez = 0;

        for current in &what_to_search {
            let now = Instant::now();
            let m = find_two(&ww, current);
            rez += now.elapsed().as_nanos();
            what_found.push(m);
        }
        measured_iter.push(rez);

        let ww_in_vec: Vec<(FloatWrapper, f32)> =
            ww.iter().map(|(&key, &value)| (key, value)).collect();

        rez = 0;

        for current in &what_to_search {
            let now = Instant::now();
            let m = find_three(&ww_in_vec, current);
            rez += now.elapsed().as_nanos();
            what_found.push(m);
        }

        measured_vec.push(rez);

        println!("{:?}", what_found);
    }
    println!("binary :{:?}", measured_binary);
    println!("iter_map :{:?}", measured_iter);
    println!("iter_vec :{:?}", measured_vec);
}

fn find_one(from_what: &BTreeMap<FloatWrapper, f32>, what: &FloatWrapper) -> f32 {
    let v: Vec<f32> = from_what
        .range((Included(what), (Unbounded)))
        .take(1)
        .map(|(_, &v)| v)
        .collect();
    *v.get(0).expect("we are in truble")
}

fn find_two(from_what: &BTreeMap<FloatWrapper, f32>, what: &FloatWrapper) -> f32 {
    from_what
        .iter()
        .skip_while(|(i, _)| *i < what) // Skipping all elements before it
        .take(1) // Reducing the iterator to 1 element
        .map(|(_, &v)| v) // Getting its value, dereferenced
        .next()
        .expect("we are in truble") // Our
}

fn find_three(from_what: &Vec<(FloatWrapper, f32)>, what: &FloatWrapper) -> f32 {
    *from_what
        .iter()
        .skip_while(|(i, _)| i < what) // Skipping all elements before it
        .take(1) // Reducing the iterator to 1 element
        .map(|(_, v)| v) // Getting its value, dereferenced
        .next()
        .expect("we are in truble") // Our
}
```

The key takeaway for me is that it is worth to use the binary search after ~50 elements. In my case with 30000 elements means 200x speedup (at least based on this microbenchmark).

Comment: The `PartialEq` implementation looks incorrect to me because it is not transitive.

Comment: @trentcl Yes. The only "correct" way is via rounding, not proximity. Also, this implementation will behave badly with large numbers.

Comment: Probably the cleanest way to do this is to use `NotNan` from `ordered_float` or `N32` from `noisy_float`. Definitely **do not** use `(self.0 - other.0).abs() < 1.17549435e-36f32`; this approach is wrong and can break `BTreeMap`. It's an approach that gets suggested a lot but has pretty much no merits.

Comment: Yes, now I get it that I should not use it. (I just do not want to edit away because that feels kind of cheating)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you wanted a std-only solution, but this is a common enough problem, so here's a solution using the crate [`ordered-float`](https://crates.io/crates/ordered-float):

#### Cargo.toml

```ini
[dependencies]
ordered-float = "1.0"
```

#### main.rs

```
use ordered_float::OrderedFloat; // 1.0.2
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut ww = BTreeMap::new();
    ww.insert(OrderedFloat(1.0), "one");
    ww.insert(OrderedFloat(2.0), "two");
    ww.insert(OrderedFloat(3.0), "three");
    ww.insert(OrderedFloat(4.0), "three");
    let rez = ww.range(OrderedFloat(1.5)..).next().map(|(_, &v)| v);

    println!("{:?}", rez);
}
```

[prints](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0306784d56d234723bc31fea69403354)

```
Some("two")
```

Now, isn't that nice and clean? If you want a less verbose syntax, I suggest wrapping the `BTreeMap` itself, so you can give it appropriately named methods that make sense for your application.

### NaN behavior

Be aware that `OrderedFloat` [may not behave the way you expect in the presence of NaNs](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/1.0.2/ordered_float/struct.OrderedFloat.html):

> NaN is sorted as *greater* than all other values and *equal* to itself, in contradiction with the IEEE standard.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we've gone over and clarified the requirements a bit, there's a couple of bad news for you:

1. You're not getting away from the requirement to have a wrapping type. As I'm sure you've discovered, this is because no floating-point type implements `Ord`
2. You're also not getting away from a combinator of some sort

First, we're going to clear up your `impl`, as they both have shortfalls described in the comments. In the future, it may make sense to use the wrapper traits in `eq-float`, as they already implement all this. The implementations at fault are `PartialEq` and `Ord`, and they both break down on a few points. The new implementations:

```
impl Ord for FloatWrapper {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.0.partial_cmp(&other.0).unwrap_or_else(|| {
            if self.0.is_nan() && !other.0.is_nan() {
                Ordering::Less
            } else if !self.0.is_nan() && other.0.is_nan() {
                Ordering::Greater
            } else {
                Ordering::Equal
            }
        })
    }
}
impl PartialEq for FloatWrapper {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        if self.0.is_nan() && other.0.is_nan() {
            true
        } else {
            self.0 == other.0
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing surprising, we're just abusing the fact that `f32` implements `PartialOrd` for `Ord` and surfacing all other implementations on `FloatWrapper` itself.

Now, for the combinator. Your current combinator will force a range of elements to be stored temporarily in memory, to then discard one. We can do better by abusing the fact that `iter()` is a **sorted** iterator. So, we can skip while we search, and then take the first:

```
        let mut first_element = ww.iter()
            .skip_while(|(i, _)| *i < &FloatWrapper::new(1.5)) // Skipping all elements before it
            .take(1) // Reducing the iterator to 1 element
            .map(|(_, &v)| v) // Getting its value, dereferenced
            .next(); // Our result
```

This yields a 10% speedup in low-element-count situations over your first implementation.

Comment: As I added to the question this solution is horrible from a performance point of view. In the case of a small number of elements, one can use a simple vector, otherwise binary search.

Comment: @KilyenOrs `let first_element = ww.range(FloatWrapper::new(1.5)..).next().map(|(_, v)| v)`